# Android development with Samsung Galaxy tablet

Tags: android

I've been learning android development and been trying to get the app on my samsung galaxy tablet but have been having some problems. I have the device connected to my computer and i can access it thought the substandard samsung app and through explorer but when i try to send the app to the device using eclipse it just defaults to the emulator.

My pc is running windows 7, i have the android and galaxy tab packages installed on eclipse and i also have the device set up with type of galaxy tab.

When i plug in my HTC Desire it works perfectly fine and i can view apps on the device, it just seems to be the galaxy tablet.

Anyone else had this problem or know of any solutions?

Thanks a lot, been frustrating me for ages now.

Comment: What do you have in your manifest regarding sdk level, screen support, etc?  You have your tablet set up with debug permissions?

Comment: I have it set to 2.2 and the standard galaxy screen size. Debug permissions may be what is causing this, on the settings screen it is blanked out so i cant tick it.

Comment: Maybe it's just your run configuration? Not sure I understand the question though. Change your Eclipse run configuration target to manual, so that you can select what device to run your application against. The default is "automatic" and it will select the first emulator instance it "knew" about when the run config was created.

Comment: try what Charlie Collins said. i think it will solve your problem. and with this also install the pc suite on your PC of your phone. i also have this problem but as i install pc suite, my problem get solved. so try this  may be your problem get solved.

Comment: I did try that and still nothing but i found out why i couldnt select USB debugging, if you have the USB plugged in then the option is greyed out. Got that turned on and everything is working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The developer tools for Samsung Galaxy tab, including drivers are [here](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows). This may be what you need, for your work.

Comment: You can now get Galaxy tab emulator through ADT in Eclipse. In my Windows PC, in Eclipse, I do "Windows" -> Android SDK Manager and select to install Samsung Galaxy tab emulator there. Or, you can just setup a 3.0 or 4.0 AVD with tablet dimensions.

Comment: I think markmanca updated the link, as I was able to download the USB drivers.